# Grub rescue fix tuturial not working and missing grub directory

Tags: boot, grub2, grubrescue

I'm trying to get puppy linux to work and I installed it, but when I took my cd out and reboot I'm shown the grub rescue problem. I tried to fix but when I got to ls(hd0,msdos1)/ part I didn't have a grub2 directory so I don't know what to do now. I reboot my computer in with the puppy linux cd but it wont reboot properly, says some error is happening. I will appreciate any help. Here is s screen shot of what I did https://ibb.co/j5WqFm .

Other answers I saw to my thread don't work, but I don't know if I'm doing them correctly. I tried other solutions I found on here doing update-grub and grub-install in grub rescue but it just said "unkown command".

Comment: this is a Ubuntu help forum, and puppy linux isn't Ubuntu, nor an official Ubuntu flavor. try the stack exchange unix & linux forum https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: puppy linux uses `grub4dos` none or the answers here will work for you. That said, grub rescue occurs when grub can not find it's config file.